# Partial derivative of an integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I have the following function (it is the incomplete elliptic integral of first kind)
$$ F(b,g) = \int_{0}^{b} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-gx^2)}} $$
I would like to compute
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial g} \ ,\ \frac{\partial F}{\partial b} \ ,\ \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial g^2} \ ,\ \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial b^2} \ ,\ \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial b\partial g}$$
so I defined

```
F[b_,g_]:= Integrate[1/Sqrt[(1 - x^2)*(1 - g*x^2)], {x, 0, b}]
```

and tried the command

```
D[F[b,g],g]
```

but Mathematica cannot compute it.
Am I doing something wrong or is there a way to do it?

Comment: Why not use EllipticF instead of an integal? E.g., `F[b_, g_] := EllipticF[ArcSin[b], g]`.

Comment: An indirect way: try `Integrate[f[x, g], {x, 0, b}] // D[#, g] &` , then replace `f` with real func.

Comment: @CarlWoll because I want to keep it as general as possible in order to modify it easily someday

Comment: Derivatives relative to "b" are trivial and why not swap the derivative relative to g and the integral?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you want to be this restrictive, but you can avoid singularities that Mathematica evidently has trouble with by making assumptions.

```
F[b_,g_]:= Integrate[1/Sqrt[(1 - x^2)*(1 - g*x^2)], {x, 0, b}]

$Assumptions = 0 < b < 1 && 0 < g < 1

D[F[b, g], g]
```

$\frac{\sin \left(2 \sin ^{-1}(b)\right)}{4 (g-1) \sqrt{1-b^2 g}}-\frac{F\left(\left.\sin
   ^{-1}(b)\right|g\right)}{2 g}-\frac{E\left(\left.\sin ^{-1}(b)\right|g\right)}{2 (g-1) g}$

The other derivatives work also.